# What's the difference between namespaces & classes?

Tags: c++, class, namespaces

In C++13/4 environment, what's the difference between a namespace and a class?

The way I see it;

```
namespace foo
{
    int a : 4;
    int b : 4;
}
```

and

```
class bar
{
    public:
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
}
```

is the same thing...

Yes, they're accessed different as such;

namespace....

```
foo::a=20;
foo::b=30;
```

class....

```
bar alpha;
alpha.a ...
alpha.b ...
```

But in general, what's the advantage of one over the other?

Comment: Classes should be used for abstraction, encapsulation, and/or OOP. Namespaces should be used for grouping.

Comment: go find the answer anywhere. you don't need a custom answer.

Comment: Aside from treating your code with "respect" in the way you portray it. Is there no fair difference? I mean, my compiler won't get mad if I switch up the order. As long as the code works, is there any back-end complications?

Comment: Your first code isn't even valid.

Comment: A better question would be, "What's the pros and cons of using a static class member, versus using a variable at namespace scope?"

Comment: WTF is C++13???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are plenty of differences. A namespace is a grouping mechanism for names, nothing more or less. On the other hand, classes:

- Are types.
- Can be instantiated.
- Can be derived from.
- Can have public, protected, and private members.
- Can have virtual functions.

And so on.

If you find yourself wondering whether you should use a namespace or a class, then you are probably just looking for a way to control the scope of names---so the choice is clear: use a namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Namespaces allow you to group entities into having a local scope rather than global scope. This is common with the standard library, `std`, for instance.

An example group of names may be streams such as `cout` and `cin`.

Without using a namespace, you have to define the namespace scope `std`.

```
std::cout << "Hello, world!";
```

With a namespace, you have revealed the scope once and no longer need to declare it again.

```
using namespace std;
cout << "Hello, world!";
```

However, in the latter case, you could not use another variable named `cout` that is user-defined or contained within another library.

Comment: The answer's a bit off, at least to me. It's *always* using a namespace. `cout` exists in `std` no matter what you do. The `using namespace std;` also makes `cout` available in the scope that it is used, which you were probably implying was the global scope. It can still be accessed via `std::cout` after that. Once you lift `cout` out of `std` and into whatever scope that statement is in, you can still have another `cout` as long as it, too, is not in that scope. For example, the library using its own namespace, or putting in a block like `{int cout;}` if this is in a function.

Comment: To be explicit, I could say 'With declaring a namespace, you have revealed the scope once and no longer need to declare it again.' I should say declare the scope rather than define it. Clearly cout exists in std regardless - My answer agrees with that.